# Pin to Power BI Dashboard not working

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, sql-server-2016

When I "Pin to Power BI Dashboard" a SSRS report, I got the response 'you don't have any dashboard, you need at least one dashboard that you have permission to pin to'. 
However, I do have dashboards in Power BI, and my Power BI tenant is nicely integrated with SSRS. I tried a lot of different scenarios without success. Everything sits in the same domain.

Any ideas?